# Velocity never hitting 0 when key released in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make it so if you are, lets say, moving right and you let go of your arrow key, you will slow down then stop, not just stop immediately. Here is how I am doing this:

```
//If you clicked right arrow key and you're not going 
//Faster then the max speed
    if(moveRight && !(vel.x >= 3)){
        vel.x += movementSpeed;
//If you let go of arrow key, slow down at 3/2 the speed you were moving
    }else if(vel.x >= 0 && !moveRight){
        vel.x -= movementSpeed * 1.5f;
    }
```

However, for some reason, this *sometimes* works. Other times, you will notice that the velocity is at about 0.00523329 or something very small like that. I don't understand why because the `else if` statement says to slow down until you are equal to 0 essentially. **I need the velocity to reach 0.** Any help in this regard is extremely appreciated!

Comment: what is movementSpeed?

Comment: What is the error exactly? That your vel.x never gets 0?

Comment: @greenPadawan some value, 5 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

Comment: @Gildraths yes, look at question, has been updated

Comment: How many precision do you need on your movementSpeed? Maybe you could round it to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else if` statement says to subtrack `movementSpeed * 1.5f`, nothing more.

Code below always prints 0.0:

```
boolean moveRight = false;
    Velocity vel = new Velocity();
    vel.x = 4;
    float movementSpeed = 3;

    while (vel.x !=  0) {
        if(moveRight && !(vel.x >= 3)) {
            vel.x += movementSpeed;
        }
        else if(vel.x >= 0 && !moveRight) {
            vel.x -= movementSpeed * 1.5f;
        }

        if (vel.x <= 0) {
            vel.x = 0;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(vel.x);
```

Maybe you forgot about loop. Please, paste more code.